# Scheduled task runs more often then needed

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Here's the schedule I have in my settings file

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'remind_to_activate_email': {
        'task': 'users.tasks.remind_to_activate_email',
        'schedule': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        'kwargs': {
            'remind_periods': (2,)
        }
    },
}
```

But for some reason job is executed each 30 minutes, and that's the timespan I used some time ago. I restarted celerybeat and removed `celerybeat-schedule` file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

All Celery tasks are queued in a database.
You should free the database at restart, or all remaining tasks will continue to run.